# WordPress remote requests post issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been writing a piece of code that will post an image via WordPress' wp_remote_request function and some very strange is happening that I can't quite understand.

It works when I test it, then when I try a few more times it fails, then I try again and it works, it's so sporadic and I can't put my finger on what the issue is. Anyone else had this issue before?

```
$boundary = wp_generate_password(24);

$payload = '';

$fileContents = file_get_contents( $file_path );

$file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime_type = $file_info->buffer($fileContents);

if($fileContents) {

    // Upload the file
    if ( $file_path ) {
        $payload .= '--' . $boundary;
        $payload .= "\r\n";
        $payload .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="' . basename( $file_path ) . '"' . "\r\n";
        $payload .= 'Content-Type: '. $mime_type . "\r\n";
        $payload .= "\r\n";
        $payload .= $fileContents;
        $payload .= "\r\n";
    }

    $payload .= '--' . $boundary . '--';

    $response = wp_remote_request( CFMH_API_URL . '/api/artwork/' . $showId . '/upload', array(
        'body'    => $payload,
        'method' => 'POST',
        'headers' => array(
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( get_option('X') . ':' . get_option('X') ),
            'content-type' => 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' . $boundary
        ),
    ));

    // Returns the url of the uploaded file
    return ! empty( $response->url ) ? $response->url : '';

}
```

**ISSUE RESOLVED** - Don't use:

```
$boundary = wp_generate_password(24)
```

As this sometimes makes invalid boundary's instead use:

```
$boundary = hash('sha256', uniqid('', true));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"? What happens when it fails?

Comment: When it fails, the API doesn't get the file. So it's not posting any of the file contents?